# Is there an English or German translation of "La Bible de Jérusalem : Edition revue et augmentée"?

Tags: history, bible-translation, mythology

An academic Theologian recommended to me the *Jerusalem Bible* as the one with the greatest amount of scholarly references. I purchased the "Reader's Edition" with the Dali illustrations (second-hand) and I managed to get all the way through.

In its preface, it says that a lot of the commentary in the original French translation had been truncated for this English version. From the Internet Archives I got a copy of the above title (ISBN 2204060631), and I am really impressed by the amount of background information that contains. Alas! my French isn't as fluent as it needs to be for effortless reading of such a dense text, so I was wondering if any of you knew about an edition of the full-blown text (specifically for the scholarly commentary, as I have the core text in English already) in one of the languages I find easier to digest.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: German: Yes, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalemer_Bibel

Comment: K-HB: Found it, thank you so much! ISBN: 978-3451294761